# Too good to be true? Ridge prediction

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, ridge-regression, caret, glmnet

I have a small data set of 18 persons. I have an outcome variable Y, and 200 predictors. These predictors were chosen based on biology and prior data.

I used the caret R package and split the data set in two, a training set of 10 persons and a test set of the remaining 8 persons.

I then trained a RIDGE model using glmnet on the 10 persons with 4-fold cross validation. I then predicted the outcome on the remaining 8 persons using the trained model.

The correlation between actual Y and predicted Y was r=0.933, which is amazingly good. Too good to be true?

Heres my codes:

```
set.seed(7)
a <- createDataPartition(dfpred$Y, list=FALSE)
training <- dfpred[a,]
test <- dfpred[-a,]

library(mlbench)
library(caret)

control <- trainControl(method = "cv", number = 4)

set.seed(7)
modelRIDGE <- train(Y~., data=training, method="glmnet", trControl=control, tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = 0))

MEA: 0.9280647
RMSE: 1.071609
R squared: 0.9748333

hm=predict(object=modelRIDGE,newdata=test[,-1])
cor.test(hm,test$Y) # r=0.933 p<0.001
```

This looks very very good. So good that I worry I have overlooked something? Any input would help, thank you!

A note on the  data:
Its clinical relevant basic research on difficult/rare human species. The data are really unique and tries på predict body glucose uptake based on serum protein concentrations. The methods are really robust and accurate. The sample size is small, but there are no larger data sets of this type available anywhere.

I also tested some other models:
[image]

Comment: Hard to tell. Have you tried making some simple model and comparing it to your model? It could be something as simple as just forecasting the train outcome mean (or something more meaningful depending on the context).

Comment: I have not done that, actually I dont know how. I did however use these models as well: lm, rf, svRadial, nnet, knn, bartMachine, lasso. rf and lasso were also good, lm was the the worst. Ridge was the best.

Comment: And what were the scores of all these models?

Comment: Alle were quite similar to ridge, only slightly worse. Do you need them specific?

Comment: It would be good if you were to include these in the question, so that we can compare.

Comment: I find the difference between the LM and the Ridge particularly interesting, did you check the variable importance for the Ridge model? It would be interesting to see how many and which of the 200 input variables are actually influencing the model prediction. Based on this you could then conclude whether the result is in line with your theoretical assumptions. This may then serve as an indicator to help determine whether its too good to be true or not.

Comment: If this is the biggest dataset possible then why are you developing a predictive model? Will you ever predict on new samples? How useful a predictive model is depends on how much bigger the population is beyond your dataset. If your sample population reflects the majority of the relevant world population then you need summary statistics not predictive modelling.

Comment: Would it be possible to post the data? That way it would be easier to comment...

Comment: I think with this sample size and provided the true solution is sparse or with particular collinearities this is perfectly well possible. Ridge penalties work perfectly well when p>>n. I fitted models with 1 million candidate features, 50 true nonzero coefficients and 500 observations and iterative adaptive ridge fits would recover 36/50 with 0 FP. That's a much less favourable variable/obs ratio than what you have...

Comment: Very nice! I cannot, unfortunately, post the data because they are sensitive and under GDPR. In biological research, ridge has been used very successfully in predicting age. This research had in the beginning maybe 5 samples and 500.000 data points (DNA methylation sites). It worked absolutely perfectly and is now an established method used in forensics and in the clinic.

Comment: @PatrickF Yes, the VIP are very well in line with what I expected. Many proteins with known functions related to glucose uptake, and also several novel ones.

Comment: @ReneBt Thanks. For now I am the only one having data like this, but my goal is to make a clinical test to be used at the doctors office. So these are preliminary data  to build upon and get grants for testing in larger cohorts.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of “building upon” research that is never reproducible and will waste grant dollars.

Comment: Maybe worth reading up on degrees of freedom first before you use caret. You can't use (or even feature select) 18 variables, let alone 200. It's mathematically impossible. One action worth considering is using PCA to create a single predictor out of variables chosen based on empirical knowledge in your field - not because glmnet tells you one variable is more important than another.

Answer (score 8):

Split sample validation can require up to 20,000 observations to perform well enough.  Otherwise the results may depend dramatically on the luck of the split.  That’s why 100 repeats of 10-fold cross-validation or several hundred bootstrap resamples provide better estimates of likely model performance in most cases.

The number of observations needed to only estimate a residual variances is 70.  The number of observations needed only to estimate the **intercept** in a binary logistic model is 96.  Estimation of a **single** correlation coefficient with precision requires 300 observations.  Those are **much** easier tasks that what you are doing, so there is no hope for looking at 200 predictors with your sample size.

This lack of hope is cemented by considering that ridge regression like lasso and elastic net depend on your being able to choose the value of penalty parameters, usually done through cross-validation.  The minimum sample size needed to reliably choose a penalty parameter is at least in the hundreds.

The only hope is to ask questions of the data that the data are capable of answering.  This involves using data reduction (unsupervised learning) on the 200 features to reduce them to one or two numbers that you can then play against Y.  Principal components analysis is often used for this purpose.  The PCs will be very unstable, but not unstable in a way that makes prediction of Y optimistic.

These issues are dealt with in detail in [RMS](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc).

Variable importance is a misleading measure in this context unless you get confidence intervals for the importance measures.  If you run the bootstrap exercise at the end of [this](https://hbiostat.org/bbr/hdata) on your data, you’ll find that the data are consistent with the “winning” feature also being the biggest loser.

Comment: Thanks for your general answer. However, I am not sure how relevant it is for my special case using ridge.

Comment: It’s relevant because you can’t use split-sample validation with non-huge datasets and because you don’t have (within a factor of at least 10) enough sample size to pick a ridge parameter.  If your sample doesn’t support estimation of a **single** correlation coefficient you certainly can’t do anything more complex than that.

Answer (score 3):

A quick-and-dirty demonstration might be instructive to supplement Frank's answer:

```
n <- 18
control <- caret::trainControl(method = "cv", number = 4)
set.seed(1)

res <- replicate(1000, {
  dfpred <- data.frame(Y = rnorm(n))
  
  for(i in 1:200) dfpred[paste0("X", i)] <- rnorm(n)
  
  a <- caret::createDataPartition(dfpred$Y, list=FALSE)
  training <- dfpred[a,]
  test <- dfpred[-a,]
  
  modelRIDGE <- caret::train(Y~., data=training, method="glmnet",
                             trControl=control,
                             tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 0, lambda = 0))
  
  hm=predict(object=modelRIDGE,newdata=test[,-1])
  cor.test(hm,test$Y)$estimate
})
```

As you can see even *total random noise* can pretty easily give values >0.9:

[image: Histogram of simulated values]

Here we have two results above >0.9 in absolute value (one is even larger than yours, with 0.94). Again, from pure noise with only 1000 simulations - thus, having a value of 0.93 doesn't really mean that much, and it is unfortunately surely not "amazingly good" at least in my view in the light of the above simulation.

Comment: Thank you! However, two out all all these test seems pretty good to me! In science we do not rely only on one test anyways, we triangulate the results. I think my result is still so good that it deserves to be followed up. I interpret your answer actually to support that statement.